# Users page does not page correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, users

The new users page on StackOverflow has a default view of Month (at least today, the first day of the week).  If you click the **Week** button to show users by week, the page shows users order by reputation this week.  If you then click another page (from the pager at the bottom), the view shows that page of the monthly view, not the corresponding weekly view.  Clicking **Week** again, shows the first page of the weekly view.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click **Users**, see that it shows the monthly view (url is `/users`)
2. Click **Week**, see that it shows the first page of the weekly view (url is `.../users?tab=reputation&filter=week`)
3. Click **[2]** to go to the second page, it shows the 2nd page of the monthly view (url is `.../users?page=2&tab=reputation`)

Using the **Next** button to go to the next page is similar.

**EDIT**: The issue is still occurring as of 3/20/2011 8:00 CDT.

Comment: +1 For perfect reproduction steps.

Comment: Just ran into this trying to find you in the list for the question you just posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, a left-over url optimization from when week was the default was not yet removed.  Now, `filter=` will always be included when paging.